# Getting KeyError when assigning value with __getitem__ method

Tags: python, bert-language-model

I want to realize the bert model.

So I built a class with `__getitem__` in it.

I can print something like `test[0]`, but when I assign a value, like `data = test[0]`, a `KeyError` occurs.

```
import random
"""
corpus_file = 'vocab'
vocab_size = 6
vocab_freq = 1
save_path = 'obj/'
max_sentence = 16

corpus -> org_line -> ope_line
corpus -> org_line -> token_list -> idx_to_token + token_to_idx
"""
class vocab():
    def __init__(self, corpus_file, vocab_size, vocab_freq,save_path,max_sentence):
        self.max_sentence = max_sentence
        self.special_labels = ['PAD', 'UNK', 'SEP', 'CLS', 'MASK']

        # output
        self.data = []
        self.idx_to_token = []
        self.token_to_idx = {}

        # ope
        self.pre_ope(corpus_file,vocab_size,vocab_freq)
        #self.save_data(save_path)
        #self.print_data()

    def pre_ope(self,corpus_file,vocab_size,vocab_freq):
        token_list = {}
        with open(corpus_file, 'r') as f:
            while 1:
                new_org_line = f.readline()
                if new_org_line != '':
                    new_org_line = new_org_line.strip('\n')
                    new_sentence = new_org_line.split('\t')
                    sentence = []
                    for tmp in new_sentence:
                        token_sentence = tmp.split()
                        sentence.append(token_sentence)
                        for token in token_sentence:
                            if token_list.get(token):
                                token_list[token] += 1
                            else:
                                new_token = {token: 1}
                                token_list.update(new_token)
                    self.data.append(sentence)
                else:
                    break
            f.close()
        token_list = sorted(token_list.items(), key=lambda i: (-i[1], i[0]))

        self.build_dictionary(token_list,vocab_freq,vocab_size)

    '''
    Special labels:
    PAD
    UNK
    SEP sentence separator
    CLS classifier token
    MASK
    '''
    def build_dictionary(self,token_list,vocab_freq,vocab_size):

        for idx, label in enumerate(self.special_labels):
            self.idx_to_token.append(label)
            self.token_to_idx[label] = idx

        for idx, (token, freq) in enumerate(token_list):
            if freq >= vocab_freq :
                self.idx_to_token.append(token)
                self.token_to_idx[token] = idx + len(self.special_labels)
                if len(self.idx_to_token) >= vocab_size + len(self.special_labels) and vocab_size != 0 :
                    break

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def print_data(self):
        print(self.data)
        print(self.idx_to_token)
        print(self.token_to_idx)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        s1,s2,is_next_sentence = self.get_random_next_sentence(item)
        s1,s1_label = self.get_random_sentence(s1)
        s2,s2_label = self.get_random_sentence(s2)
        sentence = [self.token_to_idx['CLS']] +s1 +[self.token_to_idx['SEP']] +s2 +[self.token_to_idx['SEP']]
        label = [-1] +s1_label +[-1] +s2_label +[-1]
        if len(sentence) > self.max_sentence :
            print('sentence is greater than the setting of max sentence')
        for pos in range(len(sentence),self.max_sentence):
            sentence.append(self.token_to_idx['PAD'])
            label.append(-1)
        return {
            'token' : sentence,
            'label' : label,
            'is_next' : is_next_sentence
        }

    def get_random_next_sentence(self,item):
        s1 = self.data[item][0]
        s2 = self.data[item][1]
        if random.random() < 0.5 :
            is_next = 0
            s2 = self.data[self.get_random_line(item)][1]
        else:
            is_next = 1
        return s1,s2,is_next

    def get_random_line(self,item):
        rand = random.randint(0,len(self.data)-1)
        while rand == item :
            rand = random.randint(0,len(self.data)-1)
        return rand


    def get_random_sentence(self,sentence):
        label = []
        for idx,token in enumerate(sentence):
            rand = random.random()
            if rand < 0.15:
                rand = rand/0.15
                if rand < 0.8: #mask
                    sentence[idx] = self.token_to_idx['MASK']
                elif rand < 0.9: #rand
                    sentence[idx] = random.randint(len(self.special_labels),len(self.token_to_idx)-1)
                else: # still
                    sentence[idx] = self.token_to_idx[token]
                label.append(self.token_to_idx[token])
            else:
                sentence[idx] = self.token_to_idx[token]
                label.append(-1)
        return sentence,label

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = vocab('vocab', 0, 1,'obj/',16)
    print(len(test))
    print(test[0])
    print(test[1])

    data = test[0]
```

Result:

````
2
{'token': [3, 4, 18, 12, 15, 11, 2, 7, 9, 13, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'label': [-1, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], 'is_next': 0}
{'token': [3, 6, 4, 5, 8, 5, 17, 2, 16, 5, 14, 20, 2, 0, 0, 0], 'label': [-1, -1, 19, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], 'is_next': 0}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vocab.py", line 146, in <module>
    data = test[0]
  File "vocab.py", line 90, in ```__getitem__```
    s1,s1_label = self.get_random_sentence(s1)
  File "vocab.py", line 136, in get_random_sentence
    sentence[idx] = self.token_to_idx[token]
KeyError: 4
````

`vocab` file:

```
hello this is my home   nice to meet you
I want to go to school  and have lunch
```

Comment: Can you supply a set of content for the `vocab` file that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I get a different error: `AttributeError: 'vocab' object has no attribute 'save_data'`.  Seems accurate.  I don't see a `save_data` method defined. - If I comment out that line, I get another different error `s2 = self.data[item][1] : IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: It does not matter so I delete the part .I edit the post,it can run now

Comment: there is a `\t` between `home` and `nice` , `school` and `and`

Comment: I still get: `s2 = self.data[item][1] : IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: ``` hello this is my home\tnice to meet you\nI want to go to school\tand have lunch\n```

Comment: Fixed the tab problem in the input data.  Now I get an error like what you show, except I get it for a different key: `sentence[idx] = self.token_to_idx[token]: KeyError: 10`.  I see the problem, which would be the same if `token` were `4` like you show.  `self.token_to_idx` is a map of tokens (strings) to index values, so the keys are tokens.  But you're doing a lookup in that map by the integer `10` (or `4`), and you're getting an error because the `self.token_to_idx` map doesn't have any keys that are integers.  The values are integers.  The keys are tokens (strings).

Comment: I kinda see what is going on.  Your `get_random_sentence` method works a few times when passed a `sentence` parameter that is a list of words.  But then I see a case where it is passed a list of integers, like this: `[16, 5, 14, 20]`.  In that case, it tries to look up the first "word" in the sentence, which is `16`, and that fails because that is an integer rather than a word.  I can see what you're doing in earlier runs, replacing words with index values.  Why you end up apparently processing a sentence that has already been converted from words to index values, I don't know.

Comment: Your code is hard to follow, partly because of the randomness you introduce.  I see your code working early on, so I don't see any fundamental problem with what you're doing in defining `__getitem__`.  I think you just have a garden variety logic problem in your code.  I can't spend any more time trying to figure out where your logic has gone wrong.  I'd suggest that you maybe replace the random values with constants so every run is the same, and then run your code carefully in a debugger and follow through what it is doing at each stage of execution.

Comment: if you get error then first you should check what you have in variables which makes problem - you can use `print(self.data, len(self.data), item)` and separatelly `print(self.data[item], len(self.data[item]) )` - and maybe this helps you see where code works different then you expect. And then you can try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

change the code:

```
    def get_random_next_sentence(self,item):
        s1 = self.data[item][0]
        s2 = self.data[item][1]
        if random.random() < 0.5 :
            is_next = 0
            s2 = self.data[self.get_random_line(item)][1]
        else:
            is_next = 1
        return s1,s2,is_next
```

to:

```
    def get_random_next_sentence(self,item):
        s1 = copy.deepcopy(self.data[item][0])
        s2 = copy.deepcopy(self.data[item][1])
        if random.random() < 0.5 :
            is_next = 0
            s2 = copy.deepcopy(self.data[self.get_random_line(item)][1])
            print(s2)
        else:
            is_next = 1
        return s1,s2,is_next
```